# jQuery to close a loaded div

Tags: jquery, html, hide

I load a div with POST content from an external php page in a `<div>` called `#ajaxContent` when I click a table row in the table `#tblStudents` like this:

```
$("#tblStudents").on("click", "tr", function(e){
var row_id = $("td:first a.ajaxCall", this).attr("rel");
$("#ajaxContent").html("<div id='wait'></div>");
$.ajax({
    url: "/page/editstudent.php",
    data: { 'student_id':row_id },
    success: function(data){
        $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

Now I want to add a close button inside the loaded `#ajaxContent`div.
It somewhat works when I add this code outside the `#ajaxContent` div. It hides the div but it also makes my `$("#tblStudents").on("click", "tr", function(e)` stop working until a full page refresh...

```
<button id='hide'>Hide</button>

<script>
  $("#hide").click(function(){
  $("#ajaxContent").hide();
 });
</script>
```

Is it possible to add a close function to my current jQuery script? And still be able to toggle through the `#tblStudent`- table rows and load `#ajaxContent`without a page refresh?

Comment: I would suggest trying to do `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: No change, and it still only works when the `#hide` is placed outside the `#ajaxContent`-div.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the only issue is that if you click the hide button you don't have anything to show the container on next row click.

Just adding show() method to the elemnt within row click should resolve issue

```
 $("#ajaxContent").show().html("<div id='wait'></div>");
```

If it is already visible `show()` will not cause any problems

Comment: Thank you. This partly solved my problem. I had also forgot to load the script on my loaded page wich containes the `#ajaxContent` div. Thank you!